# Finding change of variables to give linear homogeneous system

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation, change-of-variable

[image: First part of Q]

[image: Second part of Q]

I have worked out $a = -5$ and $b = -5/2$ which I'm confident is correct.  However, what I'm struggling with is understanding what matrix $B$ is meant to become.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

$$Y' = AY+b$$

Suppose $X=Y-c$, where $c$ is a constant vector.

then we have $$X'=Y'$$

and $$AY+b = A(X+c)+b=AX+(Ac+b)$$

Hence $$X' = AX+(Ac+b)$$

Hence if you pick $c$ such that $Ac+b=0$, then we have $X'=AX$, that is $B$ is just $A$.